# Ability to jump back and forth in a query no longer in 2.2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A query I used to run in 2.1.x which worked fine has stopped working in 2.2.x

#### Example

Create objects:

`Create (n:Test {val:"n"})-[:CONNECTION]->(o:Test {val:"o"})-[:CONNECTION]->(p:Test {val:"p"})`

In 2.1.8, if I run this query (note the order of the `MATCH` clause):

```
MATCH (n:Test)-[:CONNECTION*1..2]-(p:Test),(p)-[:CONNECTION*1..2]-(o:Test)
Where(n.val = 'n')
and(o.val = 'o')
and(p.val = 'p')
return n,o,p
```

I get a response.

If I run the query in 2.2.x I get no results.

Is this intended? In my view, as I have no direction indicated on the query, it should be able to jump back and forth, and each `-[:CONNECTED]-` should be able to look both ways independent of whether it's visited a node before or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting!

Futzing around with this, I re-formulated your query so that it does work under 2.2.0:

```
MATCH (n:Test {val: 'n'})-[:CONNECTION*1..2]-(p:Test {val: 'p'})
WITH n,p
MATCH p-[:CONNECTION*1..2]-(o:Test {val:'o'})
RETURN n,p,o;
```

I'm just moving your `WHERE` conditions into the match itself, and then using a `WITH` block to bind `p`, to make explicit that the `p` in your first match is the same as what's in your second match.

The way your first query is stated is a bit ambiguous.  Because you use `:CONNECTION*1..2`, the match to the `p` node could go all the way to the node you're creating with the value 'o'.  Almost like cypher is doing a greedy match (going two CONNECTION hops rather than one first).  Under that condition then, the second match can't work and you get nothing.

I can't shed light onto why this would behave differently under 2.2.0 than earlier versions, but I can see that your query formulation is a little bit funky, and reformulating as I have above does the right thing, and is also easier to understand.

Comment: Surely the second match would only not work if the first one matched 'o' as 'p' (I think this is going to get pretty messy pretty quickly). It would still match to 'p', and so should use the 'p' it matches on as the basis for the second match. I can't really see how your first match actually would do anything differently to mine, as you're still asking cypher to be 'greedy' and it would still hop to 'o'.

Comment: I see your line of thinking, you're not wrong.  That's why I don't have an answer for why the second should function differently....but it does.  In situations like this I tend to use `WITH` blocks because it disambiguates which match should happen first, and how they're connected.  Your original query isn't wrong, it's just harder to understand how it should execute, what I'm suggesting is a bit cleaner IMHO.  I also tend to put simple property matches in the actual MATCH clause because it can remove the WHERE block, no need to correlate visually nodes in MATCH to nodes in WHERE.

Comment: The example is a contrived version, the matching is generally significantly more complex, but as this replicated the problem in the smallest code I went with it. In terms of ease of understanding - I understand mine, but then I've been using it like that for a while now, so maybe I'm biased :) The reason for pushing back is that whilst your code works, for me that involves a significant code change for, when the code in my view used to work.

Comment: Fair enough - I'm sure you have other considerations that make sticking with your current formulation better.  Maybe someone can come along and provide a better answer, give it some time.  I'll just point out that my formulation has the undeniable virtue that it actually works correctly.  :)

Comment: Of that I cannot disagree :)

Comment: Right, I've checked with Neo4j (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4665) from the looks of it, it *shouldn't* have worked in versions below 2.2, so it was lucky (??) happenstance that it did. Splitting the `match` clauses up is the solution - the reason is that `Match` doesn't visit relationships more than once (in 2.2+) so the single match *pattern* I use doesn't/shouldn't work. Thank you for your solution!